# Magento access database from other application

Tags: magento

I'm building an application an i need access to my magento database, so i can get sales and warehouse info live in my application.

Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: You can open your database up to anything, although it's not very secure to do so, you might want to look at dataflow profiles and build your app to hook into that http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/dataflow.html it's not live, but you can run crons as often as you like to update the data

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Magento REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html)